# i got this error:1045error_access denied for "myuser"@myhostaddress (using password:Yes)

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

im trying to connect and check user information in c# via php and when i use webrequest i got this error:

```
i got this error:1045error_access denied for "myuser"@myhostaddress (using password:Yes)
```

its my c# related code

```
MyWebRequest myRequerst = new MyWebRequest("http://mysite", "POST", "apikey=compo#1&DBKEY=loginrequest&trans_loguser=" + usernametxt.Text + "&trans_logpass=" + passtxt.Text);
```

and its my **php connection string**

```
$connection_obj = mysqli_connect("my site", "myusername", "mypassword", "mydbname");
        if (!$connection_obj) 
        {
            echo "Error No: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
            echo "Error Description: " . mysqli_connect_error();

            exit;
        }
```

what should i do???

Comment: That's a basic MySQL error - it's saying your database username/password is wrong. *What should you do?* Enter the correct username and password - check the privileges in the `mysql.user` and `mysql.db` tables, make sure whatever user you're attempting to connect with, is allowed to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: Unrelated but please read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439